# WordPress User Role

Tags: wordpress

Can we add more 'User Role' in WordPress.org! Like we already have User->change role to->student or subscriber or author or customer etc,
In other words I want to add subscriber1, subscriber2, subscriber3 according to their research areas. Thanks in advance.

Comment: While *defining* roles is trivial, I feel that "according to their research area" is a crucial part of your question. You should specify what you mean by an "area" and how that should work with user privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can add custom user role in wordpress.. Add this code in your theme function file

```
add_role('subscriber1', __(
    'Moderator'),
    array(
        'read'              => true, // Allows a user to read
        'create_posts'      => true, // Allows user to create new posts
        'edit_posts'        => true, // Allows user to edit their own posts
        'edit_others_posts' => true, // Allows user to edit others posts too
        'publish_posts'     => true, // Allows the user to publish posts
        'manage_categories' => true, // Allows user to manage post categories
        )
);
```